# Correct nginx proxy redirect for Odoo

Tags: nginx, odoo

I'm trying to setup Odoo in Https using Nginx as reverse proxy, the domain does redirect but instead of redirect from mydomain.com to mydomain.com/web it redirect to odoo/web.

My Nginx configuration is as below

```
upstream odoo {
 server 127.0.0.1:8069;
}

upstream odoochat {
 server 127.0.0.1:8072;
}


# http -> https
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name mydomain.com; 
   rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}

server {
    server_name student.zsh.jp;

    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

# log

   access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
   error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;

   proxy_read_timeout 720s;
   proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
   proxy_send_timeout 720s;

   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    # Redirect requests to odoo backend server
 location / {
   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_pass http://odoo;
 location /longpolling {
     proxy_pass http://odoochat;
 }
  # gzip
  gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
  gzip on;
}
```

After reloading Nginx I still get redirected to an empty odoo/web address. How can I resolve this and make it redirect to the correct mydomain.com/web?

Answer (score 0):

`rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;`

Change above line to this:

`rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$request_uri permanent;`

When you use `$1` nginx takes the whatever regex matching in `^(.*)` and marks as `$1` and hence the redirect error. `$request_uri` gives you the part of the  url without the domain.